# How to extract demographic based activities from yammer through rest api?

Tags: rest, api, metrics, office365api, yammer

I am looking to extract information from a yammer through REST api.
I am more concern of extracting demographic based activity information from a  yammer page.
Has anyone worked on a similar process? or have successfully extracted through REST api?

Thanks
Harsh

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of data you can extract via the Yammer API either via REST endpoints or via exporting a spreadsheet of all network data https://developer.yammer.com/docs

If by "demographic data", you mean user profile data, such as name, job title, location, etc., then this data can be retrieved using the users.json REST endpoint, documented here: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/usersjson